# az keyvault key rotation-policy update - CLI supported version

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-cli2

From which CLI version below mentioned CLI command is supported

az keyvault key rotation-policy update

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-hsm/key-rotation#overview), Azure CLI version ***2.42.0*** or above is needed to update `az key vault rotation key policy`.

*To upgrade azure CLI use:*

```
az upgrade --yes
```

[image]

If you are already up to date, the output is as seen above.

***After checking the prerequisites, I ran below command with retention policy taken in `json` file and able to update the key vault rotation successfully.***

[image]

Comment: How to delete the rotation policy using CLI

Comment: You can use [az keyvault delete-policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-delete-policy). @user12395612